# Are there any good examples of using UIManagedDocument available?

Tags: ios, core-data

I just started a new iOS project and chose to use Core Data with UIManagedDocument. Unfortunately, this is a new class so there aren't many examples out there that use it yet. As a beginner, I would really like to learn from some sample code or tutorials about UIManagedDocument.

Are there any good examples of or tutorials about the use of UIManagedDocument with Core Data on iOS?

Comment: You may want to take a look at the WWDC sessions. Great tutorials there.

Comment: Great idea! Im going to watch it right now...thanks :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Paul Hegarty's Lectures 13 and 14 of the Stanford CS193 iPhone/iPad development class cover Core Data.  13 came out a couple days ago and covers the theory.  Lecture 14, when it gets posted will be a demo.  The whole class is being posted on iTunes U., and is outstanding.

Here's the course on Stanford's site:  http://cs193p.stanford.edu/

Visit iTunes U for the videos and slides.  Other files (including the demo files) are on Stanford's site.

Comment: found it yesterday and already watched ep. 13. It really is outstanding, best iOS Dev tutorials i've ever seen...Thanks!

Comment: Lecture 14 is out there this morning (12/9/2011).  This is the demo.  I'm looking forward to watching it myself!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example: [MultiDocumentPlusUUID](https://github.com/DonBriggs/MultiDocumentPlusUUID).

Download the project, then add your own certificate, provisioning profile, and entitlements. Compile it and run it on two devices. You can collect statistics on Cloud document update latencies.

This example is for developers, to explore the API. It evolved from on [Rick Warren's example](http://www.freelancemadscience.com/fmslabs_blog/2011/12/19/syncing-multiple-core-data-documents-using-icloud.html)